# Node and Express backend is not serving image resources while accessing from other devices in the same LAN

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mean-stack

I'm new to MEAN Stack.

My app backend which is built with Node and Express Js is not serving the images when I'm trying to access it from other devices which are in the same LAN. But it works pretty fine and loads all images in the development environment in localhost.

Most of the similar questions in SO concentrated on the problem of Node JS not serving even in localhost, but mine does serve resources in localhost pretty fine, it has issues while accessing from other devices.

I have run `npm run start:server --host 192.168.0.107` for running the server. Which is my host PC.

From other devices it loads all the text posts perfectly, except the images.

As per my search through different questions it seemed to me something is wrong with the below code in **app.js** file.

`app.use("/images", express.static(path.join("/home/user/book-app/backend/images")));`

This works fine for localhost but not for other devices.

My development PC is running a **Ubuntu 16.04**

Some clue would mean great help. Thanks for your time and effort.

Comment: To help with these sorts of questions, we have to know what EXACT URL is coming into the server for an image that doesn't work and what EXACT path on your disk contains the image you hope to match to that.  That's the only way to debug and figure out what's going on.  FYI, `app.use((req, res, next) => { console.log(req.url); next();})` inserted as the first middleware will log all incoming URLs so you can see what exactly is being requested.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response sir and the clue. Hopefully following it will help me find that bug.

Comment: FYI, you can also just look in the network tab of the Chrome debugger and see the URL of every single image in a page that was requested and see what the server responded with.

Comment: Yes I'm looking now.

Comment: try switching `app.use("/images", express.static(path.join("/home/user/book-app/backend/images")));` to a relative path.

ie assuming this is in the `backend` folder, `app.use("/images", express.static("images"));`